# ETF ranking/rating?

Tags: etf, credit-ratings

Is it possible to rank/rate ETFs from the standpoint of their riskiness?

I am aware of [Morningstar's star-based ratings](http://news.morningstar.com/pdfs/MorningstarRatingforETFsFactSheet.pdf), but based on my limited research they seem to take into account only returns and volatility of these returns. Basically, an ETF based on US Treasuries ([iShares 7-10 Year Treasury Bond ETF](http://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/ief/quote.html)) can be rated lower than an ETF of US Stocks ([iShares Core S&P Total US Stock Mkt ETF](http://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/itot/quote.html)). This is somewhat questionable, in my opinion (but apparently some regulators are fine with it).

I would appreciate any color on the subject.
Thank you.

Comment: If I uses Riskgrades from the Nasdaq web site, I get that IEF has a riskgrade of 21 and ITOT has a riskgrade of 49 . https://www.nasdaq.com/investing/risk/riskgrade.aspx